# Http requests from android app to django server

Tags: android, django, session, httprequest

I am able to log into the django server using an `Http Post request`, but when I go to see if the user is authenticated immediately after I am getting a `HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED response`.

I am using the same `DefaultHttpClient` for both the post and the get request by means of a static member.

I have already attempted adding the sessionid cookie from the `POST` request to the `GET` request as a header.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: How do you check if the user is authenticated? What's your django code for that?

Comment: http get request to domain/api/user/authenticated/

Comment: are you calling authenticate & login in django when you login via POST?

Comment: I login via post, then after that asyc task has finished, I use a get request to test the authentication in a separate asyc task

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong. There's no authenticated state for APIs on Django. When a user logs in, you should return a token which you will use to authenticate the user for every API call. For example: you associate the token "12345" for userA. Everytime the user of your app queries your API, the user passes that so you'd know it's coming from that user.

Comment: Do I pass it as a name value pair, attach it in the cookie store or as a header?  I feel like I've tried it all but if I know the standard I'll give it another look.  Thank you for your help

Comment: it will be like, http://mysite.com/api/get_user_info/?token=12345. On Django, you find the user using the token. You need to create a UserToken class in your models.py. See: https://gist.github.com/dannyroa/252a7fc9165729fbba4a